# How can i do group with sum after lookup in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.transections.aggregate(
    [

        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "activitylogs",
                localField: "transectionid",
                foreignField: "ref_id",
                as: "point"
            }
        },

        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    mobilenumber: "mobilenumber"
                },
                amount: {
                    $sum: "transectionamount"
                },
                points: {
                    $sum: "point.givenpoint"
                },
                count: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        }

    ]
)
```

here i am trying to get sum of transectionamount and givenpoint but when i run this query this is not giving any result .

mobilenumber  and transectionamount are available in transections collection

givenpoint available in activitylogs collection

how can i query get sum of transectionamount and givenpoint any one help me out
my TransectionSchema  given below

```
var TransectionSchema = new Schema({
  transectiondate:Date,
  created:String,
  transectionid :String,
  transectionamount: SchemaTypes.Double,
  mobilenumber:String   

});
```

my ActivitylogSchema

```
var ActivitylogSchema = new Schema({
    ref_id: String,
    mobilenumber:String,
    givenpoint: SchemaTypes.Double

});
```

Comment: Can you show your db schema?

Comment: @felix There should be no need for `$unwind` at all here. The problem is the naming of the variables which are all missing the `$` prefix.

Comment: The correct way is like this `{ $sum: "$point.givenpoint" }`. Field variables need the `$` in order to obtain the value. Otherwise it's just treated as a "string".

Comment: @koo005 Read the comments. Nothing wrong in the `$lookup` it's the variable names in the all the accumulators.